# How do I view or query an issue's original due date in JIRA?

Tags: jira

In JIRA, due dates can be updated regularly as project milestones change.  While this is useful functionality, sometimes it would be useful to be able to compare the originally-entered due date to the issue's current due date.

This information is retained in the [Change History database table](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Database+Schema#DatabaseSchema-ChangeHistory), but when I try to use the JQL history query functionality [provided in JIRA 5.0](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+5.0+Release+Notes#JIRA5.0ReleaseNotes-enhancementstojql), JIRA returns an error message "History searches do not support the 'duedate' field."

At this point, I'm feeling stuck. Is there any way (short of writing a custom plugin or manually parsing the database) to extract this useful data?

Comment: Better practice in general is to use the release date field in a Version. Then associate all the issues with a version. Much less updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [JIRA Behaviours Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JBHV/JIRA+Behaviours+Plugin) save the original date in custom field, using something like:

```
FormField due_date = getFieldByName("Due Date")
FormField orig_due_date= getFieldByName("Original Due Date")

if (orig_due_date.getFormValue() == '') {
 orig_due_date.setFormValue(due_date)
}
```

By saving the date to custom field you will be able to use the JQL to find and sort issues based on their original due date.